# PHP htaccess rewrite rule to same page with different parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using the following `htaccess` rules. The first one is working fine. The second rule is not working. The rule I have written for the second one is taking to the first one.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Burjalif/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products(?:\.php)?\?MC=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products(?:\.php)?\?MC=([^&]+)&SC=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ Products.php?MC=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ Products.php?MC=$1&SC=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products(?:\.php)?\?MC=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,NE,L]
```

This will ensure that you're matching only one parameter in query string.

Comment: Hai bro.This is also working.If i'm using 3 or 4 parameters what changes i need to do.

Comment: You can have any # of rules, just keep `\sHTTP` at the end of rule each `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ..` to avoid matching unwanted parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the rules.

Its entering in the first rule every time.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Burjalif/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products(?:\.php)?\?MC=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products(?:\.php)?\?MC=([^&]+)&SC=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ Products.php?MC=$1&SC=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ Products.php?MC=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hai bro.Thanks.It's working fine.If i introduced one more parameter (I mean with 3) this should be in first right

Comment: yes. 
if you have different rules that have the same base, you have to start with the more complex!

Comment: Can you please add the solution instead of telling how to fix it?